# How to communicate between php and boost library IPC?

Tags: php, ipc, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I have client and server in php communicating over shared memory, Now I would like to access this shred memory object using Boost.Interprocess how can I access it?
server.php:

```
  function create_image($str){
  // Create a blank image and add some text
  $im = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 20);
  $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
  $stringBanner=exec("date").$str;
  imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  $stringBanner , $text_color);

  ob_start();
   imagejpeg($im);
  $i = ob_get_contents();
  ob_get_clean(); 
  imagedestroy($im);
   return $i; 
  }  
  echo "\n".__FILE__."\n";
  $shm_key = ftok(__FILE__, 't');
  echo $shm_key."\n";


  $shm_id = shmop_open($shm_key, "a", 0, 0); 
 if ($shm_id) {
  //it is already created
  shmop_delete($shm_id);
  shmop_close($shm_id); 
 } 
 //you need to create it with shmop_open using "c" only
 echo "try to create\n";
 if(!$shm_id = shmop_open($shm_key, "c", 0777, 1024*4))exit(-1);


 echo "ID ".$shm_id."\n";
 $i=0;
 for(;;){
 sleep(1);
 $s="i=".$i++;
 $str=$i;
 $im=serialize(create_image($str));

 $data=serialize(strlen($im));
 $shm_bytes_written = shmop_write($shm_id, $data, 0);
 $shm_bytes_written = shmop_write($shm_id, $im, 32);
 echo $shm_bytes_written." bytes  is written: ".$s." ID = $shm_id\n";
}
```

client.php

```
<?php
$shm_key =1946222626;// ftok(__FILE__, 't');
$shm_id = shmop_open(
         $shm_key, "a", 
         0644,1024*4
         );


 $s=shmop_size($shm_id);
 $data = unserialize(
        shmop_read( $shm_id, 0, 
            31)
       );

 $im =  unserialize(
       shmop_read( $shm_id, 32, 
               $data)
       );
  // Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
 header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
// Output the image
echo $im;
```

What kind of key I should provide to Boost to get this memory region?

boost_client.cpp

```
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 
#include "sys/msg.h"

int main() 
{ 
    int msqid;
    key_t key;
    char f[]="??????";
    int mid;

    //key = ftok(, 't');
    //msqid = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    std::cout<<msqid<<std::endl;
    boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object 
    shdmem(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, 
           f,//"shmem_server", 
           boost::interprocess::read_write); 
    shdmem.truncate(1024); 
    std::cout << shdmem.get_name() << std::endl; 
    boost::interprocess::offset_t size; 
    if (shdmem.get_size(size)) 
    std::cout << size << std::endl; 
}
```

**EDIT:**

Well I found the solution in Boost IPC library Docs:

[XSI_KEY based example from boost Docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.xsi_shared_memory)

Comment: The PHP extension uses *System V IPC key*s, so which one does boost use?

Comment: Yes for sure, but it soḿehow hidden behind the scene.

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden behind the scene"?

Comment: there is a class which takes care of ftok() calls, you are not calling ftok directly to get IPC key from filename, see example in  my edit.

Comment: You should post an answer with the solution you found.

Comment: Just curios whats exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I only asked because i think there more efficient way to communicate btw your `c++` and `php` code effectively

Comment: Could you please share more effective method rather than ipc?

Comment: Write a PHP extension in C? Seriously, if you don't have the need for a standalone application, you could just integrate your boost code with PHP.

Comment: @Arman if you want share data between php and other languages try thrift, which developed by facebook

Comment: Thanks,I was looking on it, It is nice, but my project is with boost, to I stay with boost:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in what you're doing, but from what I read in your question and my knowledge, I would drop that pure IPC thing and wrap it into [ZMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) (you'll find wrapper in every language you need). It's meant to solve those kind of problems and provide a single API that could run over IPC or more common TCP socket.